# Keycloak create clientscope with a particular type using REST API

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I wanted to create a custom scope in Keycloak with the default type. I tried the following request on Kecloak 19.0.2 version

```
POST  http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/master/client-scopes

{
  "attributes": {
    "display.on.consent.screen": "false",
    "include.in.token.scope": "false",
        "gui.order": "1"
  },
  "name": "example",
  "description": "example",
  "type": "default",
  "protocol": "saml"
}
```

But it is always created with type None.

[image]

This is the same request Keycloak uses when created from UI

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You needs to call this API after call `POST /{realm}/client-scopes`

Here is [document](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/18.0/rest-api/index.html#_clientscoperepresentation)

```
PUT /{realm}/default-default-client-scopes/{clientScopeId}
```

[image]

### Demo by curl

[Get master token by curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74450861/validate-the-user-session-via-keycloak-by-username/74454346#74454346)

```
curl --location --request PUT 'http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/master/default-default-client-scopes/80854f36-5646-4fb4-aeca-581b18064c54' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer '"$MASTER_TOKEN"
```

Then you can see the result from UI.

[image]

The `clientScopeId` get  from `GET /{realm}/client-scopes` API

[image]

[Client Scopes](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/18.0/rest-api/index.html#_clientscoperepresentation)'s Body parameter do not include type
[image]

[image]